# My persistenceManager is null

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, persistent

I have Interface which is defined as

```
@Local
public interface MyPersistenceManagerLocal {

  public List<PropertyList> getPropertyList(int id);

}
```

and implentaion class for above interface is

```
@Stateless
public class MyPersistenceManagerBean implements MyPersistenceManagerLocal {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = PersistentSettings.PERSIST_NAME)
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Override
  public List<PropertyList> getPropertyList(int id) {
    System.out.println("inside MyPersistenceManagerBean.getPropertyList()");
    ......
    ......
    ......
  }
}
```

and i ma calling this in another call

```
@Stateless
public class ClientImpl implements Client {

  @EJB
  MyPersistenceManagerLocal persistenceManager;

  final List<PropertyList> dbList = persistenceManager.getPropertyList(id);

}
```

i am getting NullPointerException on

```
final List<PropertyList> dbList = persistenceManager.getPropertyList(id);
```

in debug mode i got persistenceManager is null.

i am new in EJB and JPA not able to solve this. any help why i am getting persistenceManager as null

Answer (score 3):

You are getting NPE because container haven't injected the required bean yet.
You need to set it in @PostConstruct method i.e.

```
@Stateless public class ClientImpl implements Client {

   @EJB MyPersistenceManagerLocal persistenceManager;

   private List dbList;
   @PostConstruct
   public void init(){
        dblist = persistenceManager.getDbList();
   }
```

}

Comment: Thanks Marcin, i have written final List dbList = persistenceManager.getPropertyList(id); in one of my method in class so i cannot keep this in init() and this method is called from some other method Any thing else should i try ?

Comment: Then just change it as per the answer..? Remove `final` and add a `@PostConstruct` method wherein you initialize the list.

Comment: i tried that also but it is not working (i mean added @PostConstruct in my method defination )

Comment: remamber if you annotate method with @PostConstruct annotation this method needs to have following signature <public/private/protected> void methodName(){}. No arguments are allowed